# Is there a way to access MotionEvent#getPressure in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In native Android I can get information about the pressure my user used to touch an element via [MotionEvent#getPressure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#getPressure(int)). I want to access the same information in Flutter. I have looked into [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) but I can neither find the information in `onTap` or `onPanDown`. Is there a way I can access it?

Comment: There is a callback to GestureDetector which gives the pressure information.
GestureDetector(
   onForcePressUpdate: (ForcePressDetails detail)
  {
       print(detail.pressure);
   },
)

Comment: @MohsinAbbas : That event seems to be only triggered when the pressure reaches a certain minimum.